# Can't access Newly Added WCF Methods in Web Application

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an Web application using WCF. I have added Web Reference in Web Application. I am adding methods in WCF as per my need then updating Web Reference in Web Application and it is updating successfully but can't access the newly added methods of WCF in Web Application.
Please Help me...

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Sorry Sir I am unable to display the code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I did it.
I just deleted Web Reference from Web Application and then cleaned the solution of WCF and Web Application. After that Build Solution of WCF. Then added WCF Reference through "Add Service Refeence" then Build Solution of Web Application. In this way solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do your new methods exist in the contract interface, and do they have the `OperationContract` attribute?

When you update the web reference, is it looking at a test service or your newly-modified service?

Are you running the modified service when you update the web reference, or is it that the old version of the service is running under an ASP.NET process (check your taskbar) and that is what you are updating from?

Have you rebuilt the client after updating the web reference (I know, I know, but easily missed)?

Comment: WCF Test Client is Running as per my modifications and Web Application is also updating. Even in Object Browser of added Web Reference in Web Application it shows the newly added WCF methods but the problem is that I am unable to access those along with Web Reference object

Comment: Are you able to edit your question with the web application code where you try to call the WCF service?